# How to forward a className trough a prop?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

This is the options where i want to change the `props.driftcolor` based on pick

```
<select className={classes.selectiontextbox} ref={driftstatusinputref} 
defaultValue={props.itemEdit ? props.itemEdit.driftstatus : ""}>
   <option>Akut ur beredskap</option>
   <option>Drift</option>
   <option>I beredskap</option>
</select>
```

This is the picks

```
        if(driftstatusinputref.current.value === 0)
        {
            driftcolorscheme = "red";
        }
        if(driftstatusinputref.current.value === 1)
        {
            driftcolorscheme = "red";
        }
        if(driftstatusinputref.current.value === 2)
        {
            driftcolorscheme = "blue";
        }

const Data = {
            plats: enteredplats,
            skift: enteredskift,
            rapporterare: enteredrapporterare,
            anläggningsdel: enteredanläggningsdel,
            driftstatus: entereddriftstatus,
            orsak: enteredorsak,
            datum: entereddatum,
            tid: enteredtid,
            beskrivning: enteredbeskrivning,

            //variable too look at
            driftcolor: driftcolorscheme
        }
```

And this is where i want to change the className

```
<li className={classes + "." + props.driftcolor}>{props.driftstatus}</li>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: the problem im faced with is that i dont know how to use a prop to write in className. Im currently trying the approach featured in the example where ```className={classes + "." + props.driftcolor}``` where for example```props.driftcolor = "red"``` but its not working as intended. If you think i just should have wrote that as a question instead i can edit the question

Comment: "Its not working as intended" doesn't really describe the problem or what debugging you've done.  If all you're asking is how to use props in React then you'll want to start with some introductory tutorials on React.  Props are a fundamental tool of the framework and covered by any tutorial.  If you've made an attempt and it's not working as expected in a specific way, please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate specifically what debugging observations you've made.